# Complex integral of $\frac{\cos x}{x^2+4} $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to evaluate:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2 +4} dx $$

Using wolfram alpha, it gave an answer of $\frac{\pi}{2e^2}$. Wolfram Alpha is never wrong.

**Attempt**

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos z}{z^2 +4} dx = \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{-iz} + e^{iz}}{(z+2i)(z-2i)} $$

Residue at $z=2i$ is $ \frac{\cosh 2}{4i} $

Taking this particular contour:

[image]

Expanding radius to infinity, by Jordan's Lemma $\int_\gamma \rightarrow 0$ and we are left with:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ix} + e^{iz}}{(x+2i)(x-2i)} dx = 2\pi i \times \frac{\cosh 2}{4i} $$

$$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2 +4} dx  = \frac{\pi}{4} \cosh (2) $$

Comment: @Shaktal: when you changed cos to \cos, why didn't you delete the manually added occurences of "\space"?

Comment: Please don't write "cos \space x".  Write \cos x.  The backslash not only causes $\cos$ to be unitalicized, but also automatically results in proper spacing in expressions like $a\cos b$.  It is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: thanks alot, i will bear that in mind and that will be of the utmost importance in my next post.

Comment: Are you interested in a way to compute this without complex analysis?

Comment: the question specifies complex analysis, so I guess not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $e^{-iz}$ is unbounded on the upper half-plane, Jordan's lemma does not apply. And the integral over the semicircle does not tend to $0$ when the radius tends to $\infty$, as can be seen from the differing results.

You can either split the integrand, and compute the integral of $\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4}$ over the contour in the upper half-plane - $e^{iz}$ behaves nicely on the upper half plane, since $\lvert e^{iz}\rvert = e^{-\operatorname{Im} z} \to 0$ for $\operatorname{Im} z \to +\infty$ - and the integral of $\dfrac{e^{-iz}}{z^2+4}$ over the analogous contour in the lower half-plane (where $e^{-iz}$ behaves nicely), or simply note that $\cos x = \operatorname{Re} e^{ix}$ for real $x$, and use only $\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4}$. Then Jordan's lemma applies. By parity, the imaginary part of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{e^{ix}}{x^2+4}\,dx$ vanishes, so

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{x^2+4}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+4}\,dx = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res} \left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4};2i\right) = 2\pi i \frac{e^{-2}}{4i} = \frac{\pi}{2e^2}.$$

Comment: Why is $e^{iz}$ unbounded on the semicircle? If the integral on the semicircle does not tend to zero when the radius tends to $\infty$, why do you still use Residue theorem and say the integral along the total path is just the part along the real axis?

Comment: It's $e^{-iz}$ that is unbounded. Writing $z = x+iy$ with real $x,y$, we have $\lvert e^{-iz}\rvert = \lvert e^{y-ix}\rvert = e^y$, and that is unbounded for $y \to +\infty$. $e^{iz}$ behaves nicely on the semicircle in the upper half-plane.

Comment: Ah I see, so expanding the circle and making sure integral along chord disappears only happens to bounded functions - so we choose $e^{iz}$ instead.

Nice trick up the question's sleeve!